# Using the Google API in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, react-router

I have a little react app that uses the google api to get some data from a spreadsheet. I've followed the tutorial located here:

```
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js
```

I got that working just fine. When I integrated the api script into my react app I got some errors:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/API.js

C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\my_project\src\components\API.js
18:9   warning  'authorizeButton' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
19:9   warning  'signoutButton' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
24:14  warning  'handleClientLoad' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
25:7   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
33:7   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
39:9   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
42:28  error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
66:14  warning  'handleAuthClick' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
67:7   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
73:14  warning  'handleSignoutClick' is defined but never used        no-unused-vars
74:7   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef
94:7   error    'gapi' is not defined                                 no-undef

✖ 12 problems (7 errors, 5 warnings)
```

I'm running the api call from an es6 class in my app that gets called from another module and it works with a console.log test:

```
class SheetsAPI {

  constructor() {
  this.sheetsGET();
}

  sheetsGET() {
       console.log('the class is working fine');
      //same boilerplate api code from the google API tutorial 
}

export default SheetsAPI;
```

It looks like the google api library is never loaded although I have it being called just like the tutorial recommends in my index.html right before the closing body tag. **I've tried loading the library in the head and it makes no difference.** Also i'm using react router.

My index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>


  <body class="app">
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.%PUBLIC_URL%/css/onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming your react code is executing before the last script tag in your body containing the google api is loaded. Would need to see your index.html and react code to be sure though.

Comment: It is, that's what's so weird! Err, i mean.. I've tried both ways. If you check out the google api tut the api lib is loaded after the js logic.

Comment: Is your react code loaded into your HTML before or after the script that loads the google api?

Comment: Will update with my index.html